# how to resolve error while converting CSV to jason file

Tags: c#, .net, json, csv

I have written the code with reference from one of the post on this forum but getting below error

[image]

my csv data as

[image]

how to proceed?

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript?

Comment: @IsaacVidrine this should be tagged under 'jason'

Comment: [`{"json": "lives"}`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th_Part_VI:_Jason_Lives#/media/File:Friday_the_13th_Part_VI_-_Jason_Lives_(1986)_theatrical_poster.jpg)

Comment: @KartikSachdeva lmao... im dying

Comment: Please do not post [images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). [Edit] your question with properly formatted textual code and please tag with the appropriate language so your question is more visible to those users that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can add data to a DataTable, you must add the columns you will need.  You can also check if the column exists before adding it using `dt.Columns.Contains...`.  If your CSV file has a header row you can use that to give your columns some header text.

Something like (this compiles but not actually run):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var rows = csvfile.Split('\n');

// Add the columns
var colHeaders = rows[0].Split(',');
foreach(var header in colHeaders)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(header, typeof(string));
}

// now add the data rows
foreach(var row in rows.Skip(1))
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
    {
        var data = row.Split(',');
        foreach(var d in data)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(d);
        }
    }
}
```

There are other examples available on the internet specifically for reading CSV files into DataTables ([here's one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/read-csv-file-into-data-table1)).